# Shevuos of the past

Tags: nedarim-shevuot, kabbalat-hatorah, reincarnation

If the Shevuah that we made at Har Sinai to keep the Mitzvos is still in effect, then are all Shevuot made in a past Gilgul still active, and we could all be violating Shevuot left and right?

Comment: I do not understand your question. What do you mean by violating Shabbas?

Comment: @sabbahillel He didn't say anything about Shabbas.

Comment: @shmosel Sorry I misread the question. In any case one cannot remember Shevuot made in a previous gilgul and they are no longer valid.